# Android Studio error running app: Unable to obtain debug bridge

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

My antivirus seems to have deleted or removed my adb.exe file from my SDK folder. Permission errors is preventing me to update my platform tools or installing the SDK platform tools.  "Stopping ADB server failed (code -1)" "unzip failed \adb.exe. (access is denied)". I have tried restarting my Android studio and but it didn't work. Anyone any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Remove the platform tools and redownload it again from the SDK manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, restart your computer. Next try to launch sdk manager and run update. If it fail, try to install SDK platform tools in another place and make sure that you set new location in Android studio.

Answer (score 3):

Download file from http://adbshell.com/downloads and paste in :\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe Hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: Installing new SDK will take a lot of time. Though You can download a particular file which is missing. link shared. and paste. hope dis will save your time